# suggested edits adding minor tags

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Say, there's a Java (C#, Javascript, etc) question involving array and tagged only 'java'. Two months ago nobody would lift a finger to add 'arrays' tag: the benefit is tiny, if it exists at all.

Yet, last few days I've been noticing a lot of such edits and not sure what to do. Some users even go on retagging rampage, updating every question they can lay their hands on (you can see them repeatedly in the list of pending edits).

I don't mind those guys getting their lousy 1000 reputation this way (well, only a little), but somehow I feel that the system was intended for slightly more substantial changes.

What would you do in this case? Approve or reject?

PS Some examples from the last few minutes
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11784
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11787
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11790
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11785
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11780

Comment: I would reject the edit if it doesn't add anything to the question. If you can't make up your mind then just leave it for someone else to make the decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally reject most edits like this. All the tags added in the listed examples are quite specific and most can be searched for without the tags if necessary.

I'm even more likely to reject minor edits like this when the latest activity before the edit was more than half an hour ago. An approved edit would bump the question to the home page, which would be silly to result from a really minor edit like this.

Comment: Good. Now I won't feel so cruel doing the same :)

Answer (score 8):

Feel absolutely 100% free to vote to reject edits like this.

Comment: What if it's incorrectly tagged or just lack any useful tag (like most questions in AU, where only the 12.04 appears sometimes).