# Judging if a Retag is a Minor Edit

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, too-minor

I've just found my access card to the suggested edits review queue, and find that there are a lot of low-rep retag edits in the queue thanks to this: [Kill the Retag option, use just Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit)

Now, as far as I understand, a retag is intended to only change the tags and as such at first glance will always seem a minor edit, but unless it is an outrageous suggestion, it is still a worthy edit and should be approved. However, I have noticed that most retag suggestions have at least one reject flags on it.

What is the right approach here? I have tended to approve most retag edits if they, like I said, were actually related to the question.

Comment: If a question does not need any further improvement, but the tags are definitely essential false or missing I would judge it as a valid edit.

Comment: I guess it's my fault, sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can split these into two categories of edits;

1. Edits which are *fixing* **wrongly** tagged questions.

   So a question about Internet Explorer is tagged [internet](/questions/tagged/internet)[explorer](/questions/tagged/explorer) (two tags with a completely different meaning), and the edit is correcting these to [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer).

   This is related to [what I posted yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190609/163863), and what I wrote stands;

   > The thing to be careful here is that the user is fixing all substantial issues in the post. If they're editing blatantly poor posts and only fixing the tags (smearing lipstick on a pig), reject the edit for being "too minor".

   > If however, there is little else to improve in the post, I'd "approve" it; the edits do need making; the questions are incorrectly tagged.
2. Edits which are *adding* tags to questions.

   So a question about removing elements from an Array using JavaScript is already tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[array-pop](/questions/tagged/array-pop), but the edit adds the tag [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays).

   Ok, the above example is definitely a "too minor" edit. The new tag adds no *real* purpose to the question, and the question *was* fine, indexable and searchable before the edit. See [suggested edits adding minor tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81307/suggested-edits-adding-minor-tags?rq=1)

   Suppose however the question was missing the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag; that's a pretty major omission, and an edit to add this should probably be accepted (assuming there was no glaringly-obvious issues with the post itself).

Comment: I think this is a perfect answer