# If tag only changes are too minor don't allow them to be made

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, too-minor

So I deliberately didn't make an edit solely to remove a tag to this question https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4369402 as I've been told and learned that such an edit is too minor.  As I wasn't in the mood to get a rejection or clean the whole question up I just posted a comment.  (Is that the best course of action?)  Similarly another post describes others' approaches to minor tags: [suggested edits adding minor tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81307/suggested-edits-adding-minor-tags)

It is then frustrating to see the review a handful of moments later when another low ranked user made the edit and it went through the review queue and got approved even though upon closer inspection there are other glaring problems.

Then an idea struck me. If 'tag only' edits are indeed deemed too minor to be made, then simply don't allow an edit that only changes a tag from a non-higher rep user.  And/or introduce a separate level of trust to give people the ability to add/remove tags from questions that requires less rep than that to make a full-on edit. This could remove a cause of a large body of 'too minor' edits while also encouraging users to get more  involved. Just an idea obviously.

In the end something to usher in some consistency to reviews or to allow us lower rep folk to flag a review to be reviewed would be nice :-p

**Update**
I'm aware that if the content is already perfect, it's perfectly valid. I'm more interested in other cases.

Comment: A small edit can be sufficiently major if **everything else is perfect**. There's also the question of scale, adding a major language tag is more significant than a less used, only somewhat relevant tag

Comment: @RichardTingle I guess that's the rub, I did realize that if everything else is perfect that's the case.. but seldom is perfection realized. :-p

Comment: @UpAndAdam it is preferable to vote to close your own post as a duplicate rather than editing that kind of info into your post

Comment: @psubsee2003 I did both actually.

Answer (score 4):

It's best to leave it at the discretion of the edit change reviewer.

An example of a good tag edit: when an OP incorrectly tags a question as C and / or C++, or omits the language altogether. A user who examines the question carefully and adds relevant tags has made an effective contribution: well deserving of +2 reputation if eligible.

(As for your specific example, the removal of the void-pointers tag is rather insipid: I would have rejected such an edit as too minor especially given that the question has other glaring quality issues.)

Comment: yeah, but if i do that 5 times and they are rejected 5 times I end up banned from edits for a week, which isn't fun :-p

Comment: Then, in future, don't attempt a fifth ;-)

Comment: That doesn't remotely solve or address the problem I'm pointing out.  Seeing as edit reviewers disagreed heavily on this item, which is exactly the thing I'm pointing out, you haven't actually said anything other than that Bathsheba thinks there is no problem.  2 of 5 reviewers said to reject this minor edit and you haven't addressed that.

Comment: I'd agree it's insipid (why I didn't make the edit myself) but its not insipid to the point I'm making, and this is exactly my point. You disagreed with the reviewers, yet some new low ranked user learned this was good behavior.

Comment: I'd still submit that, even excepting the odd anomaly, the edit review system works pretty well. (You are aware the the edit reviewers are audited?) Can you think of a better scheme that is not too burdensome on moderators? Your idea of blanket banning tag-only edits is not good IMO: that's chiefly what I'm out to address.

Comment: I'm aware of the auditing in that i know it exists but don't know how much better it is than the audits I see for first posts which are so obvious it's funny.. As before, disagreement on it being a problem doesn't invalidate my suggestions none of which have you even addressed.